# Send notification when password protected form is used - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, notifications

I'm looking to set up a new notification to the site admin (or one specific email address) when a user on the front-end fills out the Wordpress Core password protected form.

I have added fields to this form with the 'the_password_form' filter.

Here's my code for the custom password form:

```
add_filter( 'the_password_form', 'custom_password_form' );
function custom_password_form() {
    global $post;
    $o = '<form action="' . esc_url( site_url( 'wp-login.php?action=postpass', 'login_post' ) ) . '" method="post" class="password-form">
    <label for="Name">' . __( "Name:" ) . ' </label><input name="post_Name" type="text" placeholder="Name" required />
    <label for="Email">' . __( "Email:" ) . ' </label><input name="post_Email" type="email" size="20" placeholder="Email" required />
    <label for="password">' . __( "Password:" ) . ' </label><input name="post_password" id="password" type="password" size="20" placeholder="Password" required/>
    <input type="submit" name="post_Submit" value="' . esc_attr__( "Submit" ) . '" />
    </form>
    ';
    return $o;
}
```

I believe I need to create an action in order to $_GET the content of the form inputs and then set up a new notification to send an email that includes the content of the inputs for Name and Email (not the password).

Does anyone have any advice on how to achieve this?

In short:
Create the action that on submit of the password form gets the content of the inputs within the form, sets up a notification and then sends that notification to a specified email address containing the content of those input fields.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this function.

```
add_filter( 'init', 'email_custom_password_form' );

function email_custom_password_form() {
    if($_REQUEST['action']=="postpass")
    {
        $to = get_option( 'admin_email' );
        $subject = 'Password Protection Form Notification';
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
        $headers.= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
        $headers.= "From:<" . $to . ">\r\n";

        $message = 'Name: '.$_REQUEST['post_Name'].'<br>';
        $message.= 'Email: '.$_REQUEST['post_Email'].'<br>';

        wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there no built-in filter that handles the submission of the password protected form?

Comment: I think there's the add_action('wp_login', 'do_anything'); but might not be what you're looking for

Comment: No separate hook for that - I think so.

Comment: Wow.. that's amazing and such a small amount of code. Thank you.

I had been trying to use a plugin and custom code to grab the inputs and send it to the plugin to then send the notification, so this looks much cleaner and easier to understand!