# When password protected page is accessed : update field

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a password protected custom post type on Wordpress.
When a post is accessed (i.e. when the password is entered), I would like to update a custom field of that post with a timestamp.
Thanks to this thread :
[Send notification when password protected form is used - Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51789310/send-notification-when-password-protected-form-is-used-wordpress)
I could create the base of the code :

```
add_filter( 'init', 'email_custom_password_form' );
function email_custom_password_form() {
    if($_REQUEST['action']=="postpass")
    {
       update_field( 'resa_views', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', current_time( 'timestamp', 0 )), 12157 ); 
    }
}
```

But now I'm facing a stupid obstacle :
This code will update the post 12157, no matter which post is accessed. Of course I would like to update only the accessed post. I tried to replace 12157 by $post_id, and a few other things but no luck (i'm still learning php...)

What do I have to change...? Thank you in advance !

Comment: The last parameter of ```update_field``` method has that value hardcoded. So each time the function is called, only the post with that id will be updated.

Comment: i am aware of that, this is exactly my question : How do I make it dynamic ? Replacing by $post_id doesn't work... :/

Comment: You need to find a way to pass ```$post_id``` to your function as a parameter